# Nexus S ISO14443 comunication

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I'm looking for a way to make a **P2P** exchange in **ISO14443** with my **nexus S** in order to spy an **LLC/NDEF** communication.

I have already tried with a **NFC ACR122** reader, and a **Galaxy S NFC** phone, but the communication is always in **FeliCa** and not in **14443**.

The Galaxy S is in **4.0.3**, and my Nexus was in **4.1.1**, and now in **4.0.1**.

No way, the communication is always in **FeliCa**, but I know that Nexus S support **14443 A/B**.

Is there a way to force the **14443** communication ?
I've tried [that](http://www.grundid.de/nfc/) too, but no way to receive or send anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what results did you get? Android can either read an NDEF tag, or send a single NDEF-push/Beam message. If you want your reader to emulate an NDEF tag you have to use some software that allows for this.

Comment: @Nikolay, the OP indicated that he was looking at P2P, not reading or emulating a tag.

Comment: And I asked a question to get more details :)

Comment: @Nikolay, ok, I didn't understand why you brought up card emulation. So, the NFC stack apparently defaults to Felica as transport layer for LLC? Guess you'll need to [change the NFC stack]((http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131513/how-to-debug-the-nfc-implementation-of-android)) then, if you want to change this behavior.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov I have already try URL exchange beetwin the nexus S and the Galaxy S, with my nexus S in 4.1.1 and 4.0.1. I just want to spy a P2P exchange but with an ISO14443 comunication, and it seem my nexus S always comunicate in FeliCa. The ACR122 Reader suport ISO14443, I was thinking it's possible to let them comunicate in 14443.

Comment: @martijno Thanks, but I don't really want to root my device, I'll keep it in mind if there is no other ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but if you don't want to root the phone and/or change the firmware, you need to control the reader. Your device should work with [libnfc](http://www.libnfc.org/) and you could try using [libnfc-llcp](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-tools/source/browse/#svn/trunk/libnfc-llcp) to initiate/receive P2P communication. Then you can log/inspect, etc. messages at will.

Comment: BTW, here's a short blog post about this I came across today: http://hwit.bitstacks.com/2011/08/31/nfc-with-the-nexus-s-and-acr122-reader/ And a somewhat longer thread at libnfc.org: http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/401/p2p-communication-between-android-phone-and-nfc-reader/

Comment: Thanks, it's seems to be more complicated than that I was expected. I'm gonna try to use the libnfc ASAP.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer.