# Unable to debug using GDB

Tags: android, android-ndk

Trying to debug a native Android Application. The gdbserver and gdb-setup files have been created. A breakpoint has been set in the native code, but the debugger never gets initiated and the breakpoint is never hit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details level you've provided, it's really hard to guess what could have happened, but in such case you can start with following things:

1. Check whether you have proper [port forwarding setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#forwardports) between host and target
2. Check whether gdbserver executable at target have proper [access persmissions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-linux-file-permissions-work/) in order to be executed.
3. Try to use ["am" (ActivityManager) approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056717/how-to-debug-an-app-on-android-with-gdbserver) and connect gdb to a running proccess.